# WCF: how do I get client connection parameters on server-side?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have WCF Service (tcp/ip connection point) and would like to know from method implementations client parameters (ip, port: as many as possible).

```
class MyService : IMyService
{
  void Callme() 
  {
     How-To-Get-Client-Connection-Parameters-Here ?
  }
}
```

How can I get them? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`OperationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) for what gets passed automatically from calling client to the service.

Anything else must be passed explicitly from the client, e.g. as header fields or something.